# How to merge multiple excel workbooks into data frame use specific cell in new ID column in R

Tags: r, excel, merge

Good afternoon,

I have a folder of folders with excel files for different users. All of the excel files are identical and being with the letters "POC." I can successfully merge the workbooks into a single data frame with the code below.

However, the user's ID is in the cell A5 for each sheet, and I'd like to add that as a new column of "User ID". I'm not really sure where to start.

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='POC', recursive = TRUE)

df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x){
  read_excel(x,range="A7:E52",col_names=TRUE)
})


theData <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know both the location of the user ID and the location of the table, what about reading the sheet from A5 to E52, extracting the user ID by indexing the first element of the dataframe, and then returning only from A7 to E52?

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x){

  df <- read_excel(x,range="A5:E52",col_names=TRUE)
  user_id <- unlist(df[1,1]) # or as.character(df[1,1])
  
# keep only from the 3rd row onwards, which would correspond to A7 
  subdf <- df[3:nrow(df), ] 
  subdf$user_id <- user_id # create column where all the entries are the user_id

  return(subdf)

})

theData <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Comment: This is great! I had to set col_names = false then adjust the column names later in order for this to work, but it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value of a specific cell using `read_excel`, you can set the `range` to the single cell you want, and include `col_names = FALSE`.

As an example, you could use `read_excel('my_worksheet.xlsx', range = 'a5', col_names = FALSE)`. This produces a `tibble` with 1 row and 1 column; in other words 1 cell with your value. You can then extract this value as a single-element vector using `pull()`; `read_excel('my_worksheet.xlsx', range = 'a5', col_names = FALSE) %>% pull`.

In your example using `lapply()`, I would make a new column called `id` and assign this value to it:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='POC', recursive = TRUE)

df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x){
  read_excel(x,range="A7:E52",col_names=TRUE) %>%
    mutate(
      id = read_excel(x, range = 'a5', col_names = FALSE) %>% pull
    )
})

theData <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Additionally, it can sometimes be helpful to include the name of the spreadsheet where the data came from in the imported data. This can help with troubleshooting and finding errors, especially when you are importing lots of files. Like making the new `id` column, I often make a `file` column with this information:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='POC', recursive = TRUE)

df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x){
  read_excel(x,range="A7:E52",col_names=TRUE) %>%
    mutate(
      id = read_excel(x, range = 'a5', col_names = FALSE) %>% pull, 
      file = x
    )
})

theData <- do.call(rbind, df.list)
```